# Restart for loop on error

Tags: r

The below example does not do what is required. Namely, on error the loop does not restart, but rather runs the `1000` (or what ever length is provided) and stops. I would need it to restart every `10sec` and restart the calculation from beginning on error.

Here is snippet:

```
get_daydata <- function(n){
             message(paste("remaining runs", n))
             withRestarts(err <- tryCatch({ for(i in seq_along(he)){

                #.... some calculation .....

                }},error=function(e) { invokeRestart("rerun") }), 
                rerun = function() { message ("re-running"); stopifnot(n > 0); 
                for(i in 1:10) { Sys.sleep(1); cat(i) }; getdata(n-1) })}

get_daydata(1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this. I save the original n and then reset the inner n to orig_n on error

```
get_daydata <- function(n) {
  orig_n <- n
  message(paste("remaining runs", n))
  withRestarts(
    err <- tryCatch({
      for (i in seq_along(he)) {
        #.... some calculation .....

      }
    }, error = function(e) {
      n <<- orig_n + 1
      invokeRestart("rerun")
    }),
    rerun = function() {
      message ("re-running")
      stopifnot(n > 0)

      for (i in 1:2) {
        Sys.sleep(1)
        cat(i)
      }
      get_daydata(n - 1)
    }
  )
}

get_daydata(1000)
```

Comment: it works now as intended, however, for some reason, I'm now not able to terminate my R session via *.bat batch file command, that forces to close the R session. It seems like the R is frozen or busy...I'm not sure how to fix this...thanks